# Can I res.send an entire page in a react class for nodejs isomorphic react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hopefully this doesn't sound too ridiculous but, is it fine to do the following?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(MainLayout()));
});
```

where MainLayout() is a React class that contains the entire page.

```
var React = require('react');

var MainLayout = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
      return {
          headerStyle : {'border': '1px solid #ccc'}
      };
  },
  changeStyle: function () {
      this.setState({headerStyle: {'border': '1px solid #ab1'}});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>This is a test.</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div onClick={this.changeStyle} style={this.state.headerStyle}>
                    Hi {this.props.name}
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript" src='/public/js/app.js'></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = MainLayout;
```

I've managed to get the page to render, but my onClick doesn't seem to respond to my clicks after the page loads.

I just want to know if its possible doing this using Nodejs, React 0.14, and Babel with react presets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I was trying to do here was isomorphic react in the most basic sense.I happen to stupidly forget including the javascript to execute the component itself in the browser js.

```
reactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

It got it to work somewhat after changing a bit of code as I realised that I can render the html,head and body tags on server side, but not have react work on it on the client side, so doing a render MainLayout would cause a lot of problems. Creating another React class called 'App' and stuffing it between a div tag named 'content' works.